# Mais de um cursor na procedure Mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Preciso executar mais de um cursor na mesma procedure? Isso é possível?

```
begin
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
declare v_dia, v_rotina int;
declare v_hora time;
declare v_saldo, v_valor decimal(5,2);
declare v_flag tinyint;
declare v_id varchar (100);

DECLARE sexta CURSOR FOR (
select saldo, hora, flag, valor, sexta, id_rotina, id
from tbl_cartao
inner join tbl_dias_uso
on tbl_dias_uso.id_usuario = tbl_cartao.id_usuario
inner join tbl_rotina
on tbl_rotina.id_usuario = tbl_cartao.id_usuario and tbl_rotina.tipo = tbl_dias_uso.tipo
inner join tbl_usuarios
on tbl_usuarios.id = tbl_cartao.id_usuario
where dayofweek(now()) = sexta and  hora <=  curtime() and flag = 0 
);

DECLARE domingo CURSOR FOR (
select saldo, hora, flag, valor, domingo, id_rotina, id
from tbl_cartao
inner join tbl_dias_uso
on tbl_dias_uso.id_usuario = tbl_cartao.id_usuario
inner join tbl_rotina
on tbl_rotina.id_usuario = tbl_cartao.id_usuario and tbl_rotina.tipo = tbl_dias_uso.tipo
inner join tbl_usuarios
on tbl_usuarios.id = tbl_cartao.id_usuario
where dayofweek(now()) = domingo and hora <=  curtime() and flag = 0 
);


DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;


OPEN sexta;
REPEAT
FETCH sexta INTO v_saldo,v_hora,v_flag, v_valor, v_dia,v_rotina, v_id;
IF NOT done THEN



update tbl_cartao
set saldo = v_saldo - v_valor
where v_id = id_usuario and v_dia = 
dayofweek(now());

insert into tbl_desconto_usuarios (id_usuario,saldo_anterior, saldo_apos, data_desconto,hora_desconto)
values(v_id, v_saldo, v_saldo - v_valor, CURRENT_DATE(),CURRENT_TIME() );

update tbl_rotina
set flag = 1
where hora <= curtime() and v_dia = dayofweek(now()) and v_id = id_usuario;


END IF;
UNTIL done END REPEAT;
CLOSE sexta;

OPEN domingo;
REPEAT
FETCH domingo INTO v_saldo,v_hora,v_flag, v_valor, v_dia,v_rotina, v_id;
IF NOT done THEN



update tbl_cartao
set saldo = v_saldo - v_valor
where v_id = id_usuario and v_dia = 
dayofweek(now());

insert into tbl_desconto_usuarios (id_usuario,saldo_anterior, saldo_apos, data_desconto,hora_desconto)
values(v_id, v_saldo, v_saldo - v_valor, CURRENT_DATE(),CURRENT_TIME() );

update tbl_rotina
set flag = 1
where hora <= curtime() and v_dia = dayofweek(now()) and v_id = id_usuario;


END IF;
UNTIL done END REPEAT;
CLOSE domingo;


END
```

Comment: Não sei se está certo, porém ele não executa nunca os dois cursores

Comment: OPEN domingo;
REPEAT
FETCH domingo INTO v_saldo, v_hora,v_flag, v_valor, v_dia, v_rotina, v_id ;
IF NOT done THEN

update usuarios
set saldo = v_saldo - v_valor
where v_id = id and v_dia = dayofweek(now());

insert into desconto_usuarios (id_usuario,saldo_antes, saldo_apos, data_desconto,hora_desconto)
values(v_id, v_saldo, v_saldo - v_valor, CURRENT_DATE(),CURRENT_TIME() );

update rotina
set flag = 1
where hora <= curtime() and v_dia = dayofweek(now()) and v_id = id_usuario;

END IF;
UNTIL done END REPEAT;
CLOSE domingo;

Comment: Em seguida eu colo isso 
OPEN segunda;
REPEAT
FETCH segunda INTO v_saldo, v_hora,v_flag, v_valor, v_dia, v_rotina, v_id ;
IF NOT done THEN

update usuarios
set saldo = v_saldo - v_valor
where v_id = id and v_dia = dayofweek(now());

insert into desconto_usuarios (id_usuario,saldo_antes, saldo_apos, data_desconto,hora_desconto)
values(v_id, v_saldo, v_saldo - v_valor, CURRENT_DATE(),CURRENT_TIME() );

update rotina
set flag = 1
where hora <= curtime() and v_dia = dayofweek(now()) and v_id = id_usuario;

END IF;
UNTIL done END REPEAT;
CLOSE segunda;

Comment: pronto poste na pergunta

Answer (score 1):

é possível porém você tem que trabalhar de maneira diferente o loop, não apenas verificando a variável done, pois quando o primeiro cursor for executado ele não irá executar o segundo, então trabalharemos de outra maneira para setar se está completo ou não vamos verifica quantos registros percorrer e vamos setando um contador e quanto passar por todas as linhas setamos as variáveis done1 e done2, ficando assim:

```
begin
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE done2 INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE total_cur1 INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE total_cur2 INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE qtd_cur_1 INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE qtd_cur_2 INT DEFAULT 0;
    declare v_dia, v_rotina int;
    declare v_hora time;
    declare v_saldo, v_valor decimal(5,2);
    declare v_flag tinyint;
    declare v_id varchar (100);

    DECLARE sexta CURSOR FOR (
                                                select saldo, hora, flag, valor, sexta, id_rotina, id
                                                from tbl_cartao
                                                inner join tbl_dias_uso
                                                on tbl_dias_uso.id_usuario = tbl_cartao.id_usuario
                                                inner join tbl_rotina
                                                on tbl_rotina.id_usuario = tbl_cartao.id_usuario and tbl_rotina.tipo = tbl_dias_uso.tipo
                                                inner join tbl_usuarios
                                                on tbl_usuarios.id = tbl_cartao.id_usuario
                                                where dayofweek(now()) = sexta and  hora <=  curtime() and flag = 0 
    );

    DECLARE domingo CURSOR FOR (
                                                        select saldo, hora, flag, valor, domingo, id_rotina, id
                                                        from tbl_cartao
                                                        inner join tbl_dias_uso
                                                        on tbl_dias_uso.id_usuario = tbl_cartao.id_usuario
                                                        inner join tbl_rotina
                                                        on tbl_rotina.id_usuario = tbl_cartao.id_usuario and tbl_rotina.tipo = tbl_dias_uso.tipo
                                                        inner join tbl_usuarios
                                                        on tbl_usuarios.id = tbl_cartao.id_usuario
                                                        where dayofweek(now()) = domingo and hora <=  curtime() and flag = 0 
    );


    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    SELECT
            COUNT(*)
    INTO total_cur1
    FROM tbl_cartao
    inner join tbl_dias_uso
    on tbl_dias_uso.id_usuario = tbl_cartao.id_usuario
    inner join tbl_rotina
    on tbl_rotina.id_usuario = tbl_cartao.id_usuario and tbl_rotina.tipo = tbl_dias_uso.tipo
    inner join tbl_usuarios
    on tbl_usuarios.id = tbl_cartao.id_usuario
    where dayofweek(now()) = sexta and  hora <=  curtime() and flag = 0 ;

    SELECT
                COUNT(*)
    INTO total_cur2
    FROM tbl_cartao
    inner join tbl_dias_uso
    on tbl_dias_uso.id_usuario = tbl_cartao.id_usuario
    inner join tbl_rotina
    on tbl_rotina.id_usuario = tbl_cartao.id_usuario and tbl_rotina.tipo = tbl_dias_uso.tipo
    inner join tbl_usuarios
    on tbl_usuarios.id = tbl_cartao.id_usuario
    where dayofweek(now()) = domingo and hora <=  curtime() and flag = 0 ;


    OPEN sexta;
        REPEAT
            FETCH sexta INTO v_saldo,v_hora,v_flag, v_valor, v_dia,v_rotina, v_id;
            IF NOT done THEN

                update tbl_cartao
                set saldo = v_saldo - v_valor
                where v_id = id_usuario and v_dia = 
                dayofweek(now());

                insert into tbl_desconto_usuarios (id_usuario,saldo_anterior, saldo_apos, data_desconto,hora_desconto)
                values(v_id, v_saldo, v_saldo - v_valor, CURRENT_DATE(),CURRENT_TIME() );

                update tbl_rotina
                set flag = 1
                where hora <= curtime() and v_dia = dayofweek(now()) and v_id = id_usuario;

                IF total_cur1 = qtd_cur_1 THEN
                    SET done = 1;
                END IF;

            END IF;

            SET qtd_cur_1 = qtd_cur_1 + 1;
        UNTIL done END REPEAT;
    CLOSE sexta;

    OPEN domingo;
        REPEAT
            FETCH domingo INTO v_saldo,v_hora,v_flag, v_valor, v_dia,v_rotina, v_id;
            IF NOT done2 THEN

                update tbl_cartao
                set saldo = v_saldo - v_valor
                where v_id = id_usuario and v_dia = 
                dayofweek(now());

                insert into tbl_desconto_usuarios (id_usuario,saldo_anterior, saldo_apos, data_desconto,hora_desconto)
                values(v_id, v_saldo, v_saldo - v_valor, CURRENT_DATE(),CURRENT_TIME() );

                update tbl_rotina
                set flag = 1
                where hora <= curtime() and v_dia = dayofweek(now()) and v_id = id_usuario;

                IF total_cur2 = qtd_cur_2 THEN
                    SET done2 = 1;
                END IF;

                SET qtd_cur_2 = qtd_cur_1 + 2;
            END IF;
        UNTIL done2 END REPEAT;
    CLOSE domingo;

END
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado só não entendi na parte do select count antes de abrir o cursor

Comment: E o mysql cai toda hora que roda essa procedure, sobrecarrega